# DXA Import error on Tridion Sites

Tags: dxa

Can anyone help with the below error, which am getting while trying to run the import.ps1

[image]

Answer (score 4):

By default, the cms-import.ps1 script uses Windows authentication and uses the current Windows user to log in to the CMS.

For LDAP authentication, you should specify -cmsAuth Basic and provide username & password